# How do I DRYup Angular 2 form component?

Tags: angular, coding-style, dry, code-formatting

I have a form component,

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: '/app/contact/contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/contact/contact.css'],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [FormBuilder]
})

export class ContactComponent {

  contactForm: FormGroup;

  subjets = ['Informations', "Offre d'Emploi"];

  name: AbstractControl;
  email: AbstractControl;
  message: AbstractControl;
  subjet: AbstractControl;
  comment: AbstractControl;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.contactForm = fb.group({
      'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])],
      'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])],
      'subjet': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])],
      'comment': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20)])]
    });
    this.name = this.contactForm.controls['name'];
    this.email = this.contactForm.controls['email'];
    this.subjet = this.contactForm.controls['subjet'];
    this.comment = this.contactForm.controls['comment'];
  }

    onSubmit(form: any): void {
    console.log('Valeurs du formulaire:', form);
  }
}
```

from the snippet, it is known that the code is violating DRY, with repetitions for almost all form fields! Is it possible to further DRYup this code to minimise the repetitions?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  let group = {};

  const fields = [
    { key: 'name', len: 2 }, 
    { key: 'email', len: 2 }, 
    { key: 'subjet', len: 2 }, 
    { key: 'comment', len: 20 }];

  fields.forEach(field => {
    group[field.key] = ['', 
       Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(field.len)])];
  });

  this.contactForm = fb.group(group);

  fields.forEach(field => {
    this[field.key] = this.contactForm.controls[field.key]
  });
}
```